# return function is not rendering - react native

Tags: react-native

I am running following code for sidebar. If user is logged in I want to show logout button, else sign in button. Consider `userToken` as my variable if it's **1** it mean user is logged in

Render Function

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image source={require('./images/a1.jpg')} style={styles.img} resizeMode="cover"/>
    <Button block style={styles.btn} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',)}>
      <Icon size={18} name="home" style={styles.ico}></Icon>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Home</Text>
    </Button>

    <Button block style={styles.btn} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('History',)}>
      <Icon size={18} name="history" style={styles.ico}></Icon>
      <Text style={styles.text}>History</Text>
    </Button>

    { this.renderElement() }

    <Button block style={styles.btn}>
      <Icon size={12} name="users" style={styles.ico}></Icon>
      <Text style={styles.text}>About changeangel</Text>
    </Button>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

this.renderElement function ->

```
renderElement(){
if(userToken == '1'){
  console.log('in if condition')
  return(
    <Button block style={styles.btn} onPress={()=> this.signin()}>
      <Icon size={18} name="user" style={styles.ico}></Icon>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Sign In / Sign Up</Text>
    </Button>
  )
}else{
  console.log('in else condition')
  return(
    <Button block style={styles.btn} onPress={()=> this.signin()}>
      <Icon size={18} name="user" style={styles.ico}></Icon>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Logout</Text>
    </Button>
  )
}
}
```

In console log I can see messages but I couldn't see any button render

Comment: So you see the "Logout" button even when `userToken` is `1`?

Comment: where are you defining userToken?

Comment: @iuliu.net No I can't see Logout button even when userToken is 1

Comment: @Auticcat I'm fetching userToken from sqlite database, I cross checked in console userToken 1 is fetched

Comment: Is the token inside a state variable? Is the screen re-rendering somehow?

Comment: @Auticcat variable is under renderElement() function. Yes Screen is rendering but button isn't adding

Comment: "No I can't see Logout button even when userToken is 1 ". Your `if statement` says you should see "Sign In / Sign Up" when `userToken` is '1', why would you expect to see Logout?.

Comment: @iuliu.net No matter what I can't see any button from if or else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix:

```
renderEle() {
    const showLogout = userToken != "null";
    const showLogin = userToken == "null";

    const display = showLogout ? "flex" : "none";
    const display2 = showLogin ? "flex" : "none";

      if(showLogout){
        return(<Button block style={[styles.btn, {display}]} onPress={() => this.signOut()}>
            <Icon size={18} name="user" style={styles.ico}></Icon>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Logout</Text>
          </Button>)
      }else{
        return(<Button block style={[styles.btn, {display2}]} onPress={()=> this.signin()}>
            <Icon size={18} name="user" style={styles.ico}></Icon>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Sign In / Sign Up</Text>
          </Button>) 
      }
    }
```